# Match parameters in whenRepeated filter's layout

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

> In my application, I log events with the same message, but different
>   parameters. All LogLevel methods on the logger class have an overload
>   for accepting an `object[] args` parameter ([example1](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/ILogger.cs#L345) and
>   [example2](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#writing-log-messages)).

Therefore, there can a slew of messages such as:

```
"Some Message: Item1=A"
"Some Message: Item1=A"
"Some Message: Item1=B"
"Some Message: Item1=C"
"Some Message: Item1=B"
"Some Message: Item1=B"
...
```

Within an arbitrary time span, there can `n` messages with different `Item1` and parameters.

---

My goal is to aggregate these messages to display the occurrence of every `Some Message` in a single log message containing the number of occurrences for every parameter. Therefore, when the timeOut expires, the final message would be:

`Some Message: A (Hits: 2), B (Hits: 3), C (Hits: 1)`

Currently, my NLog.config file contains the following target and logger:

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt"
    layout="${event-context:item=filteredCount}|${message}"/>

...

<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" >
  <filters>
    <whenRepeated 
        layout="${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace:whenEmpty=${message}}"
        FilterCountPropertyName="filteredCount"
        FilterCountMessageAppendFormat="(Hits: {0})"
        timeoutSeconds="30"
        action="LogFinal"
        includeFirst="false"
        OptimizeBufferReuse="true"/>
  </filters>
</logger>
```

Comment: Im guessing you'l have to write your own custom target RepeatingWrapper ,  i havent used nlog for years, however i do know just from reading the docs there is nothing to do this out of the box

Comment: RepeatingWrapper repeats a given event - which is the opposite of my goal.

Comment: Yes you are right, however whenRepeated obviously dosnt do what you want out of the box. so you are going to have to look at the source for this (which will probably not be so complicated) and extend it

Comment: You could consider changing layout to `layout="${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace:whenEmpty=${message:raw=true}"` if wanting a filter independent of parameters, but it will not give you the group-by behavior in the "Hits" description.